# How can this MS Acess VBA script be modified to only apply to desired combo boxes and not all the combo boxes in my form?

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10

I have a form in MS Access that I've created and it has 6 combo boxes that will need to be filled based on the user's selection from an option group control (only 3 options). So if user selects option 1, then combo box 1 and 2 must be completed while 3,4,5 and 6 can be left unselected and blank. If user selects option 2, then combo box 3 and 4 must be completed and 1,2,5 and 6 cab be left blank... and you get the idea.

I copied the following code word for word from a youtuber (not sure if he was the original creator of the scrip, but here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq3myEN4Vps) for credit purposes). I want to add the modified code in the click event of an 'Add' button (most likely will put it in a case statement - case1, 2 and 3 and else). I'm not well versed with VBA like some of you, but if I get some pointers, I will give it my best shot. Also... this code seems to rely on the object's 'Tag' property '_value' or something and a module for the function IsNullOrEmpty... Thx in advance.

```
Private Sub CmdGenAdds_Click()

 Dim ctrl As Control
 str = Empty

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
        If IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl) Then
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(119, 192, 212)
            ctrl.BorderColor = RGB(157, 187, 97)
            str = str & ctrl.Tag & vbNewLine
        Else
            ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
            ctrl.BorderColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl

If IsNull(str) Or str = "" Then
             'executes some queries, etc, etc
Else
    MsgBox "Please select a value for all the fields listed." & vbNewLine & _
    String(52, "-") & vbCrLf & str, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Data Validation"
Exit Sub
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Form is in Single display mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a value to combobox Tag property.

Combos 1 and 2 will have 1
Combos 3 and 4 will have 2
Combos 5 and 6 will have 3

Add criteria to nested If Then and eliminate the IsNullOrEmpty function call:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
       If ctrl & "" = "" And ctrl.Tag = Me.opt1 Then
           ctrl.BackColor = RGB(119, 192, 212)
           ctrl.BorderColor = RGB(157, 187, 97)
           str = str & ctrl.Tag & vbNewLine
        Else
           ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
           ctrl.BorderColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If you would rather not loop through all controls on form, name the six comboboxes like: cbxData1, cbxData2, cbxData3, cbxData4, cbxData5, cbxData6.

```
For x = 1 To 6
    With Me("cbxData" & x)
    If .Value & "" = "" And .Tag = Me.opt1 Then
        .BackColor = RGB(119, 192, 212)
        .BorderColor = RGB(157, 187, 97)
        str = str & .Tag & vbNewLine
    Else
        .BackColor = vbWhite
        .BorderColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I will have to decide which method to use since I like both. The script for the 1st method will be much shorter, but the second method is very clear to me. I just did not know how to write the syntax and spent hours researching and the samples I found made it more confusing. So I don't know how I can get a -1 on my question since I tried my best to find the answer but just don't know enough. For an expert this might be peanuts but for someone like me it is not. Thx though I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Downvote was probably because no attempt to adapt code to your situation, no testing and no error info and actually did not include all the code. Why would you say the first method script is shorter? They are both 12 lines. And in fact, the second doesn't declare and set object variable so procedure is actually shorter.